# Daily report of modified objects in an instance, compared to second instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get a high-level report of schema differences (modified/added/dropped objects) when comparing all databases in two instances. 
Both instances have the same databases, usually with the same schemas, but when one gets updated I would like a report with all the changed objects (Database + Object Type + Object Name). 
I would like to schedule this to run on a daily basis.

The instance databases are all restored from a create-spript daily (created by a Powershell script), so I can't query systables for creation date.

I need a free solution, I have SSMS, Visual Studio 2013, TFS.

I have tried with Powershell, but I can't get it do do what I want (probably my inexperience).

I have the create-scripts for both instances, so I could make some sort of file-compare with a report, but that would be much harder to read than a list of objects that have been addad/dropped/modified.

Ideally, I would like a mail with a list with the following heading: DatabaseName, ObjectType, ObjectName, ModificationType (Created/Dropped/altered)

Comment: First thought I have is to use SQL Compare from RedGate and Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you. I have used their products extensively in the past. However, in this case, I need a solution that does not require any license fees..

Answer (score 0):

Create a job that sends a mail with the result of this request:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but the instance databases are all restored from a create-spript daily, so I can't query systables for creation date. Sorry I did not make that clear, I have edited my question.